# How does .NET JIT determine how to add numbers

Tags: c#, clr, jit, cil, opcode

CIL has single opcode for adding numbers without overflow check - **add**.

This C# code:

```
int a = 10;
int b = 20;
int c = a + b;
```

produces the following IL code:

```
IL_0000:  ldc.i4.s   10
IL_0002:  stloc.0
IL_0003:  ldc.i4.s   20
IL_0005:  stloc.1
IL_0006:  ldloc.0
IL_0007:  ldloc.1
IL_0008:  add
IL_0009:  stloc.2
```

How does JIT at run-time determine, which type of x86 addition it should use (FPU opcode **faddp** for floats or **add** for integers)?

Comment: Not familiar with IL but isnt "i4" right there for that reason? To mean "int, 4 bytes"? That would imply the type data is persisted until the add.

Comment: I think that's it - changing `int` to `float` produces `r4` instead, `double` is `r8`..

Comment: .NET IL is not like Java bytecode, there's only one add.  It was designed to always be compiled, never interpreted.  The jitter can always figure out the operand types in the process of generating code and thus pick the correct machine code instruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CLR tracks the types of values on the evaluation stack, so it knows that right before the `add` instruction, the types of the two topmost values on the stack are `int32` in your code. This means that it knows that it has to emit the instruction for adding 32-bit integers.

If you write code where the CLR won't be able to figure out the types of the operands of `add`, your code will be unverifiable and will probably result in garbage native code.